# AngularJS: attach function to controller load

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to attach a function that gets called any time a controller is loaded by angular?

I would like to replicate this:

```
(function (angular) {

    angular.module("mymodule")
    .controller("mycontroller", [

        function () {
            console.info("mycontroller loaded");
        }

    ]);

})(angular);
```

So that the `console.info("mycontroller loaded");` line is executed automatically without having to insert that line in every controller.

Is there an event/provider that I can use for this?

Comment: write directly in controller without function?

Comment: Do you mean a function that is loaded every time a controller in your app is called? Like when you switch pages and the controller changes the function loads? you could do that with a service that you instantiate on the first line of every controller.

Comment: @JoeLloyd yes, only, I don't want to repeat the same line on every controller. I was just speculating if there was an event or something else to which I could attach to achieve the same result without having to remember to add the line on every controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a service**

Create a Load service and instantiate it in each controller.

```
.service('loadService', function(){
  return{
    loaded: function () {
        console.info("mycontroller loaded");
    }
  }
})
```

Now your controller can look like this

```
.controller('myController', function(loadService){
  loadService.loaded();
  //the rest of your controller//
})
```

Any functionality you would like to share between your controllers can be done with a service or a factory.

Comment: I don't want to repeat the same line on every controller. I was just speculating if there was an event or something else to which I could attach to achieve the same result without having to remember to add the line on every controller.

Comment: if you want a controller to do something you have to tell it. this would be the cleanest way of doing it I think since it refractors your code out and only requires you to add 2 words.

Comment: I think QO is looking for something like interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (ng_event, ng_newUrl, ng_oldUrl){

 });
```

it is called every time within controller when you load it.

```
(function (angular) {

   angular.module("mymodule").controller("mycontroller", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

   $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (ng_event, ng_newUrl, ng_oldUrl){

   });

  }]);

})(angular);
```